# Remove two elements in XML using linq

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I want to remove two elements from an XML using LINQ if one value is null.  What I tried was this:

```
xml.Descendants("MarketingSpecial")
   .Where(Function(m)  Document.Descendants("MarketingPrice").Value() = "0.00")
   .Remove()
xml.Descendants("MarketingPrice")
   .Where(Function(m) m.Value() = "0.00")
   .Remove()
```

But it removes `MarketingPrice` correctly, but removes `MarketingSpecial` everywhere.  How can I only remove `MarketingSpecial` when i remove `MarketingPrice`?

The xml is formatted as follows:

```
<Inventory pt="0.159">
    <Vehicle>
       <MarketingSpecial><![CDATA[ Yes ]]></MarketingSpecial>
       <MarketingPrice>0.00</MarketingPrice>
    </Vehicle>
</Inventory>
```

Comment: How is your XML formatted? In the `Special`, you're looking at `Document.Descendants` as opposed to the single descendant in the `Price`. Are the prices under the specials?

Comment: @krillgar I went ahead and edited the answer with the format of the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look for the sibling `MarketingPrice` as opposed to any within the entire Tree when looking for the `MarketingSpecial`'s `MarketingPrice`.

```
xml.Descendants("MarketingSpecial")
   .Where(Function(m)  m.ParentNode().Descendants("MarketingPrice").Value() = "0.00")
   .Remove()
```

Within your function inside the Where clause, your `m` is the current `MarketingSpecial` node. Go up to its parent, and check its descendants for the `MarketingPrice`. That will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the elements you need to delete in the same query:

```
xml.Descendants("Vehicle").Where(Function(m) m.Element("MarketingPrice").Value() = "0.00")
                          .SelectMany(Function(e) e.Elements()
                                                   .Where(Function(x) x.Name="MarketingSpecial"
                                                                   Or x.Name="MarketingPrice"))
                          .Remove()
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case, there is other information that I omitted that's part of the xml.  I have to only remove those two elements.